# ARM loop cmp issue

Tags: assembly, arm

This is homework. I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong for quite a while now. The assignment is:

> Consider the following code in C:

```
int foo(int a, int b) 
 {   
 if (a > b) return 0;   
 if (a == b) return b;   
 return a + foo(a+1, b); 
 }
```

> Implement this function in assembly. After branching back from your
>   function, the output should  be as follows.   If the user enters 4
>   then 10: 4  10 49
>
> END
>
> If the user enters 10 then 4:
>
> 10 4 0
>
> END

My code so far is:

```
@main program
_start:        
    mov sp,#0x100000        @ set up stack

    ldr r4,=0x101f1000    
    @ ASCII codes stored 
    @ at [r4] get printed

    @ get input
    bl get_int
    mov r5, r0
    bl get_int
    mov r6, r0

    @ mov a to r0 b to r1
        mov r0, r5
        mov r1, r6

    @ branch to the function you write
        bl  foo

    @ print the number in r0 after branching back from your function
        bl  print10

        @ branch to exit
        b my_exit

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       Your code starts here      @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

foo:
        cmp r0,r1
        blt Less
        bge More
        mov r0,r1
        b Exit
Less:
        mov r3,r0
        add r0,r0,#1
        add r3,r3,r0
        cmp r0,r1
        blt More
        mov r0,r3
More:
        mov r0,#0
Exit:
        bx lr
```

The problem I am having is when I run it, no matter what numbers I input, I always get an output of 0.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do at `Less:`, but it's not right. What you _should_ do there is call `foo` with the arguments `a+1, b` and return the result of that plus the current value of `a`.

Comment: `bge` is not [the right condition](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/07/16/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes) for `More`, it is just `bgt` as you want equal to return a different value (a==b or R0==R1).  You can use recursion or *inline* the rest of `foo` and not use recursion.  I would check what [a compiler does](https://godbolt.org/g/ivsdCn).

Comment: Thank you artless. I changed it to bgt and was able to more pinpoint what I was doing wrong. In the end I changed it to ble L2 and in L2 did bne. Got it to work for the results I need. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is how to pass parameters and return a value. On the ARM ABI, the equivalent of:

```
int less(int a, int b)
```

Would be:

- `a` (first parameter) is passed in r0
- `b` (Second parameter) is passed in r1
- Return value has to be written to r0
- Mov `lr` to `pc` to return from function

So to call the `less` function, you need to:
- Move `a` to r0
- Move `b` to r1
- Call the function (`bllt`) - Make sure to call `bl` (Branch and link) instead of a simple `b` (Branch). The branch and link form copies the address of the instruction after the `bl` to permit a return
- Get the result from r0

You also need to be carreful that when you call a function, `r0-r3` will be corrupted. And if you need to modify the other registers, you need to push them on the stack and restore before returning.